# track user on revisit?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, uniqueidentifier

I have made a project which tracks the activity of user and based on that I create a graph.
How can I create a *random cookie id* and most importantly drop his respective cookie id on his browser so that next time he visits ,I can **detect the user**.
I have succesfully inserted the data in to my table and represented it.
Any help?

Comment: Have a look at the manual's entry http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: sure,I will jeff,but if possible,can you tell me what should i do to track the user

Comment: go with setcookie and $_COOKIE to set and retrieve the cookie info

Comment: Ok,after i set my cookie info,how do i retrieve it back,thats my point.does the link have info about retrieving cookie info back?If yes,i will delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code has not been tested but it should give you and idea of what to do:

```
<?php
if( !isset($_COOKIE('visitor') ) {
  $visitorID = 'abc';
  $expires = time()+60*60*24*365;  // 1 yrs time
  setcookie('visitor', $visitorID, $expires, '/');
  echo "Hello new visitor";
} else {
  echo 'Welcome back';
}
//--- other code goes here
?>
```